# How get get Failover cluster volume information using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, server, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

The screenshot below is Win2012R2 Failover Cluster Volume. Those volumes are mapped from SAN through FC connection.
I am trying to get this volume information as shown in screenshot by using powershell.

But I dont see there is any command for getting what I want.

I have tried "Get-ClusterResource", "Get-Cluster", "Get-ClusterDisk" as well as "Get-ClusterSharedVolume" which returns nothing.

Any idea how?

[image]

Comment: To my best knowledge to get info about LUN,wwn etc You best use 3rd party tools provided by the SAN people, likes of 
acpadmin, environment, fcadmin, sasadmin, storage show, etc 
I cannot open the attached screenshot from my corporate network sadly so please disregard this comment if it's not valid for Your problem :)

Comment: In collection scripts I created for Hyper-V clusters I used commands like `Get-Disk`, `Get-Partition`, `Get-PhysicalDisk`, and `Get-Volume`. Then on top of those I usually run some CIM commands like `Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSCluster_DiskPartition -Namespace root\MSCluster`. You usually have to cross reference multiple commands to get the full picture. I could provide you one of my old scripts if you wanted to play around with it.

Comment: @Jon Dechiro Are all your Volumes mapped through LUN from SAN?

Comment: @RootLoop Yes, the volumes are from a SAN via FC.